# Multiple User Registration MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i have this api script and people are going to have the HWID and it has to add their information to their account when they open a program, but when there is multiple user with the same HWID it screws up and doesn't add their info to the account, here's the code I'm using:

```
$cpukey = mysql_escape_string($_GET['cpukey']);
    $ip = mysql_escape_string($_GET['ip']);
    $pcname = mysql_escape_string($_GET['pcname']);
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table") or die(mysql_error()); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $time = time();
        if ($row['ip'] = '-' and $row['pcname'] = '-'){
            mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET pcname = '$pcname'
            WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '-'");
            mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET ip = '$ip'
            WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
            if ( $row['expire'] > $time) {
                $str1 = "NOT EXPIRED";
            }else{
                $str1 = "EXPIRED";
                mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET expired = 'Yes'
                WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET banned = '1'
                WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
            }
            echo $str1;
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET pcname = '$pcname'
            WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
            mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET ip = '$ip'
            WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
            if ( $row['expire'] > $time) {
                $str1 = "NOT EXPIRED";
            }else{
                $str1 = "EXPIRED";
                mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET expired = 'Yes'
                WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET banned = '1'
                WHERE cpukey = '$cpukey' AND pcname = '$pcname'");
            }
            echo $str1;
            }
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if ( $cpukey == $row['cpukey'] ) {
       if ( $row['banned'] == 0) {
        $str = "Not Banned";
            break;
       }else{
            $str = "Banned";}
            break;
    } else {
            $str = "Don't Exist";} 
    }
    echo $str;
```

Now I want the code to add the users' info if their info hasn't been entered yet, witch their info would be "-" and then when they open the program it will change their info to something else... In other words make it where people can have the same HWID and it won't give any errors...

Comment: What is the structure of your MySQL table? Any unique or foreign key constraints?

Comment: No, But here:
`<?php
$host=""; 
$username=""; 
$password=""; 
$db_name=""; 
$tbl_name="members"; 
$table="Account"; 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
if ($row['ip'] = '-' and $row['pcname'] = '-'){
```

It should be

```
if ($row['ip'] == '-' and $row['pcname'] == '-'){
```